LLVM invalid cast opcode for cast from 'i64' to 'i64'
I'm trying to use LLVM Create and replaceAllUsesWith to modify the (A+B+C) calculation to (A*B)-C
The ReplaceInst.cpp code I wrote is this,
// Traverse Instructions in TheModule
void TraverseModule(void)
{
        for( llvm::Module::iterator ModIter = TheModule->begin(); ModIter != TheModule->end(); ++ModIter )
        {
                llvm::Function* Func = llvm::cast<llvm::Function>(ModIter);

                for( llvm::Function::iterator FuncIter = Func->begin(); FuncIter != Func->end(); ++FuncIter )
                {
                        llvm::BasicBlock* BB = llvm::cast<llvm::BasicBlock>(FuncIter);
                        std::vector< llvm::Instruction* > AddInsts;

                        for( llvm::BasicBlock::iterator BBIter = BB->begin(); BBIter != BB->end(); ++BBIter )
                        {
                                llvm::Instruction* AddInst = llvm::cast<llvm::Instruction>(BBIter);

                                // if( Inst->isBinaryOp() ) {}
                                if( AddInst->getOpcode() == llvm::Instruction::Add )
                                {
                                        if (AddInst->getNumOperands() != 2) {
                                                std::cerr << "Error: Add instruction does not have exactly 2 operands." << std::endl;
                                                continue;
                                        }

                                        llvm::LLVMContext& context = AddInst->getContext();

                                        llvm::Instruction* MulInst = llvm::BinaryOperator::Create(
                                                        llvm::Instruction::Mul, /* Opcode */
                                                        AddInst->getOperand(0), /* S1 */
                                                        AddInst->getOperand(1), /* S2 */
                                                        "multmp",       /* Name */
                                                        AddInst /* BeforeInst */ );

                                        // replace sign extend(sext)
                                        llvm::Instruction* SextInst = llvm::CastInst::Create(
                                                        llvm::Instruction::SExt, /* Opcode */
                                                        MulInst, /* S1 */
                                                        llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(context), /* S2 */
                                                        "sextmp", /* Name */
                                                        AddInst /* BeforeInst */
                                                        );

                                        llvm::Value* CPointer = AddInst->getOperand(1);

                                        // replace load
                                        llvm::Instruction* LoadInst = new llvm::LoadInst(
llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(context),
                                                        CPointer,
                                                        "loadtmp",
                                                        AddInst
                                                        );

                                        // replace sub
                                        llvm::Instruction* SubInst = llvm::BinaryOperator::Create(
                                                        llvm::Instruction::Sub,
                                                        SextInst,
                                                        LoadInst,
                                                        "subtmp",
                                                        AddInst
                                                        );


                                        AddInst->replaceAllUsesWith( SubInst );

                                        AddInsts.push_back( AddInst );
                                }
                        }

                        for( int i=0, Size=AddInsts.size(); i<Size; ++i ) AddInsts[i]->eraseFromParent();
                }
        }
}
                       

This is the Test.c code
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int Add(int*arr,int*brr,int*crr,size_t n)
{
     crr[n]= arr[n]+brr[n]+n;
     return crr[n];
}

int main()
{

     int N=0;
     printf("Input N (0~5)\n");
     scanf("%d",&N);
     int crr[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
     int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
     int brr[5]={2,3,4,5,6};
     int result = Add(arr,brr,crr,N);
     printf("...(%d MUL %d) SUB %d = %d\n" ,arr[N],brr[N],N,result);
}

The vimdiff of the original ll code and replaced ll code seems correct, and it is what I intended.
When when I make ll code from Test.c code and compile it, below error occurs.

Can I write the cpp code without replacing the signextend part? Or is there any more optimized to this problem?
I tried getting rid of replacing the signextend part, but it didn't work.

Well, you can't extend an i64 to i64. Trty adding something like if((static_cast<IntegerType>(MulInst->getType()))->getBitWidth() < 64) around the SextInt creation.

https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#id251 For reference.
